# HTML5 canvas drawImage() does not draw large images on Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, html5-canvas

If i try launch code in localhost. This not showing image with mozilla firefox but in other browsers show successfully. If i try load little image load successfully

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="containerScaled"></canvas>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var canvasScaled = document.getElementById("containerScaled");
    var ctxScaled = canvasScaled.getContext("2d");

    var imageWidth = 500; 
    var imageHeight = 500;


    img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        ctxScaled.drawImage(img, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
    };

    img.src = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/Fronalpstock_big.jpg'
});
</script>
```

Comment: I confirm the misbehavior with that image. There appears to be something about that specific image that causes it to fail loading in FF.  Other large images work fine in FF with no failure.

Comment: I've actually gotten this to work. Using your exact code in firefox... I wouldn't be surprised if its going to be an issue on some machines because its a 10,000px wide image your scaling down to 500px.

Comment: Maybe someone can advise where to go what is this problem

Comment: I have a very similar problem. In my case, the HTML5 canvas works fine with images up to the width 8000 px, and doesn't work for images having width beyond that. This is for Windows 7 64 bit Firefox latest version 32. But the site works completely fine in Windows 8 Firefox latest version 32.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it looks in this context:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var canvasScaled = document.getElementById("containerScaled");
    var ctxScaled = canvasScaled.getContext("2d");

    var imageWidth = 500; 
    var imageHeight = 500;


    img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        ctxScaled.drawImage(img, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
    };

    img.src = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/Fronalpstock_big.jpg'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="containerScaled"></canvas>
```